# How can I pray the full salah when stuck at a small airport for an extended period of time?

Tags: salat, travelling

I will be travelling very soon. I know the ruling whilst you are in flight where you can do a 2 rakat whilst sitting on the plane.

There will be 1 full day where I will be travelling in between airports (3 different airports) through short haul flights. The flights seem to fall where they depart just after the times for salah (Zhur, Asr, Maghrib).

In the airport, there will not be a place for prayer due to it being a small airport. The question I have is how can I pray the full Salah given this situation? Or should I just pray in the departure lounge whilst sitting?

What is the best thing to do? It's a bit of a conundrum - I cannot pray the full Salah due to the timing of the flight but at the same time since the flights are short haul flights, I want to try and pray the full Salah.

If it is permitted to pray short Salah whilst in flight (except for Isha since I will be in a hotel for the night), then how should I pray the Salah?

- Zhur: 2 Rakat Fard
- Asr: 2 Rakat Fard
- Maghrib: 2 Rakat Fard

Is this how it is done when shortening the prayer whilst travelling?

Comment: I think if there is appropriate place in airplanes(like in saudi airlines they have) than pray in plane, or if its not the case, and you know that before plane lands you will be missing a prayer in plane, than you can pray than prayer in advance with last prayer. Its better. Or if you didn't know and you just missed a prayer in plane, you can make it on airport after landing. You just need 1x4 feet space for prayer. Don't do it sitting in airport lounge, spread any clean cloth and pray on it.

Comment: And magrib is 3 rakaat farz for musaafir/traveler. its not 2. fajr and isha are also 2 besides.

Comment: You are allowed only to shorten the four rak'a fard prayers. That means maghrib is always performed 3 rak'a no matter what.

Comment: Thank you. so 2 fards for Zhur and Asr but for Maghrib it must be 3. Can I perform these whilst sitting?

Comment: IMO yes, "if you fear the reaction of people", but if you fear that it is not valid, than you should redo it once you are on the ground, back home or in a hotel. Here are some relevant posts [Praying on an extended flight](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/14475/praying-on-an-extended-flight), [How does one pray during an airplane flight?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/587/how-does-one-pray-during-an-airplane-flight)

Answer (score 1):

If there's no prayer room available, I just find the quietest spot available and pray.

- I use a large handkerchief to pray on (placing it diagonally), which is not too cumbersome to carry around.
- I use whatever luggage I'm carrying as a [sutrah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutrah).

People just walk past and ignore me (unless they're Muslim, then they smile at me).

---

This question [How does one pray during an airplane flight?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/587/17163) adresses praying while in flight.